# JPA Serialization

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I'm working with JPA 2.0-EclipseLink-Hibernate 3 on MySQL 5. My classes structure is like below (I simplified it)

```
public class Status implements Serialization {
    private String name = null;

    public Status(string n) {
        this.name = n;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT")
public class Account {

    public static final Status ACTIVE = new Status("AC");
    public static final Status DISABLE = new Status("DI");

    private Status status = null;
    private long id = 0;

    public Account(long id, Status s) {
        this.id = id;
        this.status = s;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="status")
    public Status getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public setStatus(Status s) {
        this.status = s;
    }
}
```

Now, my question is, when I insert a new Account using EntityManager.persist, the program throws an exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr...'
>   for column 'status' at row 1

And after I added a new Account manually into the database, then I select it, the program say:

> Exception Description: Could not deserialize object from byte array.
>   Internal Exception: java.io.EOFException Mapping:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[status-->ACCOUNT.status]
>   Descriptor:
>   RelationalDescriptor(net.serenco.serenekids.model.bean.account.Account
>   --> [DatabaseTable(ACCOUNT)])

Please tell me how to control what value will be written to DB, and by the way, please help me fix these errors. Thanks in advance!

**---------------- EDIT ----------------**

I have managed to find out the solution myself. It is:

```
@Embeddable
public class Status implements Serialization {
    ...

    protected String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    protected void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT")
public class Account {
    ...
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( {
            @AttributeOverride(name="name", column = @Column(name="status") )
    } )
    public Status getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you did this on purpose but you're returning the status for the getId method.

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo. Thank you for pointing it out. I've edited it!

Comment: I think this is caused by a difference between the JDBC string encoding and the one used by the database. Could you please provide your database connection URL?